# API data inconsistently binding to Buttons using View Binding

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using View Binding. The API call works, I have a print statement proving that I am receiving data properly, only the binding isn't working consistently.

Once I receive a response from the API, I parse it (proven working), and apply the text on buttons. For some reason, it works a few times at the start, then stops working for a bit, then works again. I am testing it by repeatedly opening and closing the fragment once it is done loading (or doesn't load after 10-15 seconds after the response).

I use similar code for another fragment, and it works perfectly there. I can also tell it's not a rate-limit issue as I still get a response when it isn't working.
Here are the outputs when they are working and when they arent:

Run output when the data isn't properly binded:

```
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea2844e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xea283720)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea2844e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xea283720)
I/System.out: **API RESPONSE HERE**
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea2844e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xea283720)
```

Run output when the data is properly binded and the text shows up:

```
RUN OUTPUT WHEN THE DATA IS PROPERLY BINDED
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea2844e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xea283730)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea2844e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xea283730)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea2844e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xea283730)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea2844e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xea283730)
I/System.out: **API RESPONSE HERE**
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea2844e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xea283730)
```

This is the output from the API response if it is relevant:

```
I/System.out: {"trivia_categories":[{"id":9,"name":"General Knowledge"},{"id":10,"name":"Entertainment: Books"},{"id":11,"name":"Entertainment: Film"},{"id":12,"name":"Entertainment: Music"},{"id":13,"name":"Entertainment: Musicals & Theatres"},{"id":14,"name":"Entertainment: Television"},{"id":15,"name":"Entertainment: Video Games"},{"id":16,"name":"Entertainment: Board Games"},{"id":17,"name":"Science & Nature"},{"id":18,"name":"Science: Computers"},{"id":19,"name":"Science: Mathematics"},{"id":20,"name":"Mythology"},{"id":21,"name":"Sports"},{"id":22,"name":"Geography"},{"id":23,"name":"History"},{"id":24,"name":"Politics"},{"id":25,"name":"Art"},{"id":26,"name":"Celebrities"},{"id":27,"name":"Animals"},{"id":28,"name":"Vehicles"},{"id":29,"name":"Entertainment: Comics"},{"id":30,"name":"Science: Gadgets"},{"id":31,"name":"Entertainment: Japanese Anime & Manga"},{"id":32,"name":"Entertainment: Cartoon & Animations"}]}
```

This is how the fragment is called from the GameActivity, its parent. I am just making a fragment transaction from a placeholder FrameLayout to the fragment.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder, CategoriesFragment())
    .commit()
```

Here is how the button text is being binded within the Fragment (simplified). This code is located inside of onViewCreated():

```
thread {
    val api = API()
    val json = api.request("https://opentdb.com/api_category.php")
    println(json)
    if (json != null) {
        // Returns 4 categories to be binded, Categories(name, id)
        val categories = api.parseCategories(json)
        // Array of buttons
        val buttons = arrayOf(
            binding.btnChoice1, binding.btnChoice2,
            binding.btnChoice3, binding.btnChoice4
        )
        requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
            // Binds text to buttons
            for (iterator in buttons.indices) {
                buttons[iterator].text = categories[iterator].name
            }
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the binding isn't working consistently"? The text doesn't show up? If you print out the list of categories inside `requireActivity().runOnUiThread` what do you see?

Comment: @TylerV binding as in the text isn't being bound properly to the view. Your suspicion was right, if I put a print statement inside the runOnUiThread, it prints the first few times (like above) but after, I get the following log: `I/ryan.trivia_ap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 6165(680KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 793us total 123.321ms
I/ryan.trivia_ap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 6767(734KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 22.674ms total 136.962ms`... 

Do you have any idea what this would mean?

Comment: I'm not sure if those outputs are relevant or not, I'd start adding print statements at different spots in your code (e.g. just after you set `categories`) to try to see what's going on. Also, so you know the terminology, setting the text on the buttons is not the same as view binding. If you later change the categories array the button text wouldn't change (it isn't bound to that).

Comment: Will do, thank you for your input